# What is the appropriate HTML 5 element for a hero unit/showcase?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

A lot of marketing and content-heavy sites showcase the page's primary content using large text and/or images, sometimes with a slider, containing a call to action for signing up for a service, or downloading an app, etc.. I'm not sure what this design element is called, I got the term hero unit from twitter bootstrap:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#typography

I think most of you know what I'm trying to describe... If it's not clear I can add screenshots or links to this question.

I looked at a few different sites, and some put this hero unit inside a `ASIDE` element, others use `SECTION`, `ARTICLE` and even `HEADER`. [Using twitter bootstrap as an example again](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html):

```
<header class="jumbotron masthead">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Bootstrap, from Twitter</h1>
    <p>Simple and flexible HTML, CSS, and Javascript for popular user interface components and interactions.</p>
    <p class="download-info">
```

Is `HEADER` the most appropriate tag for this type of content? Or should I use `ASIDE`, `ARTICLE` or `SECTION`?

Answer (score 13):

From [HTML5 doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/), where they discuss how to mark up the main content:

> An assistive technlogy like a screenreader can find the main content because it is the first thing inside a page that isn't a header, nav or footer.

So I would just wrap your "hero unit" in a `section`. Each related group of content on a page should be grouped in its own `section`, with the first section being the start of the main content.

I would however second @net.uk.sweet's suggestion to frequently use a HTML5 outliner. Also, check out the HTML outlining article on the [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document#The_HTML5_Outline_Algorithm), it was really helpful for me.

Comment: What you say makes sense so I've removed my stab at defining a structure leaving the more general advice only.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Fair enough - I'll remove my reference to it then!

Comment: Used the wayback on the dead MDN link and found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements... seems the original document may no longer be available there.

Comment: Each `<section>` should be identified, typically by including a heading (`<h1>`-`<h6>` [ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)), so if you don't use headings inside your hero (like when it's just an image carousel without any text) then you shouldn't use `section`. Use `aside` or just `div`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking at the w3 specification for each of the tags you're considering using and reading the description and usage examples. Of course you only need to look at the debate spawned by a seemingly simple question such as [when to use an article tag](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) to realise that this stuff is pretty subjective. However, reading the spec will leave you in a better position to formulate your own opinion:

1. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element
2. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-aside-element
3. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element
4. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element

I do think that your `header` tag should be contained in a further sectioning element so that it's not hierarchically equal to other page headers within the element that contains it. What that sectioning element should be will depend on the content of your "hero unit" and how that content relates to the rest of the page.

Finally, check your work frequently in an [HTML5 document outliner](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) to get a feel for the structure of your new section and the page which contains it.